# Individual Chosson Shas Volumes

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-bavli

Are there any stores or websites which happen to sell individual Chosson Shas volumes (i.e. Oz VeHadar, Vilna Chadash and the like)?

Comment: Beigeleisen in Boro Park. I got one volume of a set of mishnayos there and one volume of an aruch hashulcha. They're really good at finding random seforim.

Comment: @Moses do they have a website?

Comment: No. but their phone number is online. It's literally a chasidishe hole in the wall, but they have an amazing array of seforim, and can get some rare stuff.

Comment: Try Mizrachi Books ,he has thousands of great seforim,and he his extremely knowledgeable, the place is a hidden gem.

Comment: @sam where is it located? do they have a website?

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi - [Here's](http://stores.ebay.com/jewishbookshop/) his eBay store.